# Proof of invariant lines of a linear differential system.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, invariant-theory

Show that the only invariant lines for the linear system $x' = Ax$ with $x \in \Bbb {R^2}$ are the lines $ax_1+bx_2=0$ where $v=(-b,a)^T$ is an eigenvector of A.

I understand that if this line (let's call it L) is invariant for the system, it means that for all $x_o \in L$, $e^{At}x_o \in L$ for all real t. What I do not understand is really how to go about proving this. Any assistance would be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x_o\in L=\{(x_1,x_2):ax_1+bx_2=0\}=\langle(-b,a)\rangle$, since there is only one line perpendicular to a given line in $\Bbb R^2$. Thus, if $Av=\lambda v$, then $e^{At}x_o=e^{\lambda t}x_o$, and hence $e^{At}x_o\in L$. Conversely, let $L’$ be a line in $\Bbb R^2$ such that for each $t\in\Bbb R, e^{At}x_o\in L’$, and in particular $x_o \in L’\cap L$. Then since $\dim L’=1$, $e^{At}$ must keep vectors on $L’$, on $L’$. Let $t\to -\infty$, then $(0,0)\in L’\cap L$. Since $L$ and $L’$ intersect at two points, they are the same line.